[hyperledger-fabric]Hyperledger Fabric 2.2 Issue: Config Update Failure After TLS Certificate Expiration
I'm encountering a problem with my Hyperledger Fabric 2.2 network and could use some assistance.
**️ Network Setup:
Orderer Nodes: 5
Peer Organizations: 10
Consortiums: 10
(One organization is part of two consortiums)
**⚠️ Issue Details: One of the organizations has a TLS intermediate certificate that expired. I successfully updated the TLS intermediate certificate in the application channel config block before the expiration date. However, due to operational delays, I couldn't update the orderer system channel before the certificate expired. This resulted in the following error when attempting to apply a config update:
2024-11-04 13:38:21.248 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'croxchain-orderers-channel': initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Consortiums sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: CA Certificate is not valid, (SN: 85076825076483007851870499652303227021): could not obtain certification chain: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2024-11-04T13:38:21Z is after 2024-10-28T15:59:59Z
**✅ What I've Tried:
Updated the TLS intermediate certificate in the application channel config block successfully.
Verified that the new certificate is correctly configured for the application channel.
**❓ Question: Given that the TLS intermediate certificate for one organization has expired and I'm unable to update the orderer system channel before the expiration, what steps can I take to complete the update process and resolve the BAD_REQUEST error? Are there specific procedures for handling expired certificates in the system channel, especially in a multi-consortium setup?
**ℹ️ Additional Information:
Fabric Version: 2.2
Current Time in Error Message: 2024-11-04T13:38:21Z
Certificate Expiration Time: 2024-10-28T15:59:59Z
Any help or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated! 
need help for updating this organization's tls intermediate certificate in the system channel.
